# Suppose that $\lim a_n = 0$ Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+a_n\frac {x}{n}\right)^n = 1$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\lim a_n = 0$ Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+a_n\frac {x}{n}\right)^n = 1$$

I was trying Leibniz theorem earlier but it was not working. Was I using the right one?

Comment: do you mean $a_n x$?

Comment: @Alex The question they gave me only had $a_n$

Comment: @Krish Fixed it

Comment: Wasn't this asked just the other day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that $$\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n \to e^t=\exp(t)$$ as $n \to \infty$ with $a_nx:=t$ you obtain that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a_nx}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \exp{(a_nx)}=\ldots$$ Due to the continuity of the exponential function $f(t)=e^t$ you can interchange the $\lim$ operator with the $\exp$ operator to conclude that $$\ldots=\exp(\lim_{n\to \infty}a_nx)=\exp(0)=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 1 because the expression you have can be upperbounded by $e^{a_n x} \to_n 1$ and lowerbounded by $e^{-a_n x} \to_n 1$.

Comment: Hm. Which theorem could I show that by?

Comment: Definition of $e$, Euler's constant